# Closed Messages conversations reopen after reopening the app

Tags: macos, mojave, messages, catalina

I sometimes close conversations cluttering the sidebar but they don't stay closed after quitting and reopening the app, they reappear. The only way to keep them closed is to also restart my mac. Does anyone know how to solve this ?